# Viewing Environment.Exit(x) codes in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-error-reporting

I have an application which throws Environment.Exit(100) code. Where can I view all the logs for my application in Windows? Where is it logged?

Comment: It is up to the programmer to write to either their own log file or to the event logs. There is no standardized log that catches all the errors from all the apps.

Comment: @EBGreen So, if I want to view that exception I need to write my own log in the windows logs to filter it out?

Comment: You need to either: 1) Write the log to one of the existing Windows Event logs, 2) Register your own Windows Application Event log and write to that, 3) Write to a completely different log. Often a simple text file is used or less common a DB.

Comment: @EBGreen Just to make sure, the client has asked me to exit with these codes. This means he implemented option 2, is that right?

Comment: No. That probably means he is launching the app in an automated fashion and catching the return code from the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit codes are not logged by Windows.  Your program should do it's own logging (whether you use the Event Logs for that is up to you).

An easy way to check the exit code on a one off basis is to use [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) and [`%errorlevel%`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html).

e.g:

```
start "Window Title" /wait "c:\path\yourProgram.exe"
echo %errorlevel%
```

Comment: My client has a way of viewing every code my application exits with and asked me to send different codes. Any idea how he did that so I can do that too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  There are [standard run-time exit/error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx), plus you can choose to exit with whichever code you'd like, for whatever reason. If you're not intentionally throwing 100 on exit, then something is wrong (specifically, according to the standard error codes, "ERROR_TOO_MANY_SEMAPHORES").  To me it sounds like the customer is asking you for known/custom exit codes that you've implemented, so that he can build an accurate alert template for some monitoring software.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET: You can easily capture exit codes by launching a program through a batchfile.